# JTextArea or JTextPane Set Highlighted Text Color

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jtextarea, jtextpane

I am trying to change the color of a the highlight in either TextArea or TextPane or even any others.

Note that I am looking for changing the color of:

[image]

And not the text.

I have also took a look at the `JTextArea`'s `setHighlighter()` function but it seems that I will need to input an anonymous `Highlighter` class which I have absolutely no idea how to implement all the overrides.

```
jta.setHighlighter(new Highlighter() {
    @Override
    public void removeHighlight(Object tag) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void removeAllHighlights() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void install(JTextComponent c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public Highlight[] getHighlights() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void deinstall(JTextComponent c) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void changeHighlight(Object tag, int p0, int p1)
            throws BadLocationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public Object addHighlight(int p0, int p1, HighlightPainter p)
            throws BadLocationException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried setting in the `paint(Graphics g)` method? like `g.setColor(Color.color);`

Comment: Just tried, they highlight the text only. Also they don't un-highlight the text after you un-highlight it

Comment: Try the answer below that should help you more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mean the "normal" highlight color (when you drag your mouse over the text), this can simply be achieved by

```
textArea.setSelectionColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
```

(or whatever color you want it to have.)

If you want to programmatically highlight a character sequence in your text area:

```
String searchedWord = "word";
int pos1 = textArea.getText().indexOf(searchedWord);
int pos2 = pos1 + searchedWord.length();
try {
    textArea.getHighlighter().addHighlight(pos1, pos2,
            new DefaultHighlighter.DefaultHighlightPainter(Color.LIGHT_GRAY));
} catch (BadLocationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

(The same works for a `JTextPane` too)

Comment: Both lead to changing the color of the text. What I meant was, as shown above, change the color of the highlighter. Perhaps I should make the pointer less fat?

Comment: @MoonCheesez Really? It doesn't change the text color for me... [Click me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2embp.png)

Comment: I think I found the problem... I set the color to `new Color(26, 38, 59, 27)` Therefore it returns a highlight color so dim that I could not see and it set the text color inverted.